# Validate a checkboxlist in MVC - check that at least 1 item is checked (true)

Tags: sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In my view, I have my code like this (it populates the list of things that can be checked or not checked.)

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.HazardClassificationCheckBoxes.Count; i++)
{
        if (i % 3 == 0)
        {
            @:
            <tr></tr>
        }
        <td>
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.HazardClassificationCheckBoxes[i].isSelected, new { @class = "custom-checkbox" })
            <label>@Model.HazardClassificationCheckBoxes[i].hazardname</label>
            @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.HazardClassificationCheckBoxes[i].hazardid)
            @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.HazardClassificationCheckBoxes[i].hazardname)

            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.HazardClassificationCheckBoxes[i].isSelected, "", new { @class = "error" })
        </td>
}
```

With this validation however, it highlights next to every item that is not checked.

What I want is that it shows only one message that at least one item in this group needs to be checked.

Here is the view model (where I created my hazard checkbox list to call in the action result):

```
public List<tbl_Hazard_Classification> HazardClassificationCheckBoxes { get; set; }
```

Here is the class of the checkbox

```
public partial class tbl_Hazard_Classification
{
    public int hazardid { get; set; }
    public string hazardname { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Please select a hazard!")]
    [MustBeTrueAttribute(ErrorMessage = "Please select a hazard!")]
    public bool isSelected { get; set; }
}
```

And in the controller, I have this code:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

Question: how to show only 1 message for at least 1 item to be checked in the entire list?

Comment: I can think of a workaround. You can submit the form through AJAX instead of with the submit button, and perform a "pre-validation" on client-side using javascript.

Comment: you could add a field to your view model for this.  Initialize something like "error" to ""...  then update it with error message and send as query value on redirect.  Just use a <span class="text-danger">@Model.error</span>  (It'd be good to add client-side validation too... just add error and disable submit if a choice isn't made)

Comment: @pcalkins I did this - was also not successful with this way.